# RFC 5649 Key wrapping with SunJCE provider

Tags: java, aes

I'm trying to implement [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudhsm-import-keys-openssl) OpenSSL hybrid wrapping using SunJCE provider and unwrap the key to AWS HSM, unfortunately failing miserably so far.

```
Command: unWrapKey -f wrapped_key_material -w 2883603 -noheader -l test -kc 3 -kt 0 -m 7

Cfm3CreateUnwrapTemplate2 returned: 0x00 : HSM Return: SUCCESS

Cfm2UnWrapWithTemplate2 returned: 0xad 

HSM Error: Operation Failed. Invalid inputs passed
```

I'm assuming OpenSSL `id-aes256-wrap-pad` cipher corresponds to `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding` in `WRAP_MODE`

From OpenSSL doc:

```
aes-[128|192|256]-wrap-pad key wrapping with padding using 128/192/256 bit AES
```

This is what I have so far:

```
    // Generate 256bit AES KEK
    KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    keyGen.init(256);
    SecretKey masterKey = keyGen.generateKey();

    // Load public RSA key
    byte[] publicKeyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(publicKeyFile));
    String publicPem = new String(publicKeyBytes, "ASCII");
    publicPem = publicPem.replaceAll("^-----BEGIN .* KEY-----\n", "");
    publicPem = publicPem.replaceAll("-----END .* KEY-----$", "");
    byte[] encoded = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(publicPem);
    PublicKey publicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(encoded));

    // Load private RSA pkcs#8 der
    byte[] privateKeyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(privateKeyFile));
    PrivateKey privateKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyBytes));

    // Set RSA cipher parameters
    OAEPParameterSpec spec = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-1", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA1, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT);
    Cipher oaep = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1ANDMGF1Padding", "SunJCE");
    oaep.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, publicKey, spec);

    // Set AES cipher parameters
    byte[] ivBytes = { 
        (byte) 0xA6, (byte) 0xA6, (byte) 0xA6, (byte) 0xA6,
        (byte) 0xA6, (byte) 0xA6, (byte) 0xA6, (byte) 0xA6,
        (byte) 0xA6, (byte) 0xA6, (byte) 0xA6, (byte) 0xA6,
        (byte) 0xA6, (byte) 0xA6, (byte) 0xA6, (byte) 0xA6,
    };
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
    Cipher aes = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "SunJCE");
    aes.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, masterKey, ivSpec);

    // Wrap private key with AES KEK
    byte[] wrappedPrivateKey = aes.wrap(privateKey);

   // Wrap AES KEK with public RSA key
    byte[] wrappedMasterKey;
    try {
        wrappedMasterKey = oaep.wrap(masterKey);
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
            "AES key should always fit OAEP with normal sized RSA key", e);
    }

    // Concatenate wrapped KEK and wrapped private key
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    outputStream.write(wrappedMasterKey);
    outputStream.write(wrappedPrivateKey);
    byte wrappedKeys[] = outputStream.toByteArray();
    Files.write(new File("wrapped_key_material").toPath(), wrappedKeys);
```

My uncertainties are mainly with my initialization vector, they pass hex A65959A6 to OpenSSL

```
    for (byte b : iv) {
        String st = String.format("%02X", b); 
        System.out.print(st);
    }
```

My IV is `A6A6A6A6A6A6A6A6A6A6A6A6A6A6A6A6` AWS HSM consider `0xa6a6a6a6a6a6a6a6` as default IV

Not sure if my concatenation is done correctly too.

Comment: "I'm assuming OpenSSL id-aes256-wrap-pad cipher corresponds to AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding in WRAP_MODE". **Why would you assume that?** Hint: Maybe you can find a better one [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/specs/security/standard-names.html#cipher-algorithm-names)?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes+ or better [in 17](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/security/standard-names.html#cipher-algorithm-names) which [added the 5649 algorithms](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/17-relnote-issues.html#JDK-8248268) (plus 17 is still supported while 9 is past EOL)

Answer (score 1):

CBC is not the right one, my IV is wrong too.

Correct cipher is `AESWrapPad` introduced in Java 17 and IV should be `{(byte)0xa6, (byte)0x59, (byte)0x59, (byte)0xa6}` now i can import to AWS HSM.

Maven support for Java 17 starts from 3.8.x